# Techniques to measure similarities between instances and a dataset

Tags: mathematical-statistics, unsupervised-learning, similarities

I'd like to get a similarity measure between my dataset and a set of instances. For example, let's say I have a dataset with 4 features and n rows -

```
     a    b  c    d
0  0.0  0.5  1  0.5
```

I'm looking to find a similarity metric that will specify how similar this instance <8,4 5,1> is to the entire dataset. I'd appreciate if I could get a technique that doesn't make any assumption regarding the distribution of the data and also isn't computationally intensive (although a tradeoff might have to be made at some point).

Comment: I don't get what your "<8,4 5,1>" means and how it is meant to be connected to the "dataset example" above. I also don't understand what the leading 0 is doing there.

Comment: <8,4,5,1> is just an new instance to the dataset. The 0 indicates the serial number which can be safely ignored.

Comment: So you mean 8,4,5,1 are the values for which the first observation takes 0,0.5,1,0.5? Re your question: You could use the distance between the new observation and the distribution mean vector. For some reason I suspect that this is not what you're after, but it could help understanding if you'd say what's wrong with it.